# Loop unable to get all records

Tags: php, loops, woocommerce

I've created new record fields in woocommerce order report, everything works fine but report is not displaying all product names which customer has ordered multiple items. Someone asked me to use `echo "product <br>",` but i'm not sure where to place to start loop or `$row`

```
 // Output report rows

foreach ($sold_products as $product) {

    $row = array();


     /*usama*/
    $order = wc_get_order($product->order_id);
    $customerName =  $order->get_billing_first_name().' '.$order->get_billing_last_name();
    $billingCity = $order->get_billing_city();
    $billingAddress1 = $order->get_billing_address_1();
    $note = $order->get_customer_note();


    //echo $product->order_id;
    //echo $customerName.$city.$billingAddress1;
    //echo '<pre>';print_r($order);exit;
     /*usama*/
    foreach ($_POST['fields'] as $field) {

$terms = get_the_terms($product->product_id, 'product_cat');
$categories = array();
$cats = '';
if (!empty($terms)) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) $categories[] = $term->name;
    $cats = implode(', ', $categories);
}

$values = [
            'order_id' => $product->order_id,
            **'product_name' => html_entity_decode(get_the_title($product->product_id)),**
            'quantity_sold' => $product->quantity,
            'gross_sales' => $product->gross,
            'product_categories' => $cats,
            'customer_name' => $customerName,
            'city' => $billingCity,
            'address' => $billingAddress1,
            'customer_note' => $note,
            'ceremony_date' => $order->get_meta( '_billing_myfield12', true ),
            'ceremony_time' => $order->get_meta( '_billing_myfield13', true ), 
];

$row[] = $values[$field];

    }
```

Comment: It looks like you are basically asking the same thing again, as you did already under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60002760/loop-does-net-get-all-records In that case, you should at least tell us, what progress you were able to make so far, based on the feedback you got already.

Comment: This is because old post was dead and i did not get much help to resolve this issue. I'm unable to get all product names in report.

Comment: You barely addressed the feedback you got there. If this was to be considered “dead” – then mostly due to _you_ not staying with it, I would say. And here I don’t see any improvement of the question either, or that you yourself managed to gain any new insights, or even ask a bit more precise.

Comment: My bad! but could you please make this issue solve for me? I'm learning this way