# Loop unable to read all Access records

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

This question has already been asked, but no answer [Loop unable to get all records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60041655/loop-unable-to-get-all-records).

I've tried everything that crossed my mind to resolve this isue. Now I simplified code and Access DB but still I was unable to solve this problem.

Last record in Access DB - row0 is : 97, rows1 : 0097 but loop only reads 95 (0095) as the last one.

Here is vb.net code :

```
    Dim cn As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source As New BindingSource

    cn = New OleDbConnection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBKand & "; Persist Security Info=False;"

    Try

        ds = New DataSet
        tables = ds.Tables
        cn.Open()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM [DBKandidati]", cn)
        da.Fill(ds, "DBKandidati")
        cn.Close()
        Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
        source.DataSource = view


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Dim someVar As String

    Dim test As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        someVar = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(1).ToString()
        test = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString()
    Next

    MsgBox(test)
```

EDIT :
I don't know if I'm doing the same thing now with `DataTable` as before with `DataSet` but I'm getting the same result.

```
 Dim OLEDBString As String = "Select * FROM [DBKandidati]"
        Dim dtb As New DataTable
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBKand & "; Persist Security Info=False;")

        cn.Open()
        Dim dad As New OleDbDataAdapter(OLEDBString, cn)
        dad.Fill(dtb)
        cn.Dispose()
        cn.Close()

        Dim LastValue As String
        For Each row As DataRow In dtb.Rows
            LastValue = row.Item("IDK")
        Next row

        Dim numberOfRecords = dtb.Rows.Count

        MsgBox(numberOfRecords)

        MsgBox(dtb.Rows(numberOfRecords - 1)(0).ToString())
```

First value (rows count) is correct = 97, second value that I'm getting is 95 which is incorrect, as it is shown in image below, last value in column 0 is 97. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is how DB looks like, it has 97 rows.
[image]

Comment: Do you know it is only 95 by the value of 'test', or by inspecting Rows.Count at runtime? Without an 'order' in your select statement, you could be receiving the rows in an unexpected order.

Comment: Record 97 is the last unique record (col0), 95 is what loop reads as the last one, same thing happened with record 92, 63 and so on. Skipped those problematic records by manually entering values (as I looked for solution).  How can I order records when reading rows? The point here is to to find last value in column 1 (biggest number value without zeros), but those are strings (00097) I am not sure if I am able to use max function?

Comment: Firstly, don't create a `DataSet`, get a `DataTable` from it and then create a `DataView`. Just create a `DataTable` and bind that directly. The `DataSet` is pointless if you only need one `DataTable` and the `DataTable` already has a `DataView` associated with it and that's where the data comes from when you bind it.

Comment: Your code is rather crazy. That loop is very dodgy. If you want to find the maximum value in a `DataTable` then use its `Compute` method, e.g. `Dim maxId = CInt(myDataTable.Compute("MAX(Id)"))`. What's last isn't really relevant if you're not sorting, as suggested.

Comment: Thank you jmcilhinney. Max function solves my problem, but I would like to understand what is going on with code above/database. I deleted last 10 rows and problem is gone, 87 rows, last value is 00087 when using code above. Deleting one row I'm getting same incorrect results 96/00095.

Comment: Recordset is not getting records in necessary order. Use ORDER BY clause in SQL and see if you get correct result. Instead of looping, using DESCENDING order and then just read the first record. Even use TOP 1 to reduce amount of data retrieved. `SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC;`.

Comment: I am worried about why you want the maximum IDK. Don't add one and expect it to be a valid primary key. Another user could be doing the same thing at the same time and one of you is going to fail. Use the auto number feature of the database.

Comment: Learn to use `Using...End Using` blocks. If you have an error and `cn.Close` is never reached, then your connection will be left flapping in the breeze.

Comment: @Mary new IDK is stored until button is clicked, then record is created and necessary file is renamed. Thet's the best I could think of

Comment: Ordering fixed this issue. Thank you all.